# Do i need an antivirus with fedora 16 KDE?

Tags: linux, fedora, anti-virus

This is the first time i am operating Linux . I just installed Fedora 16 KDE and i need to know if i really need a antivirus ? I have heard that antivirus isn't needed with linux. Is it so ?

If i need to install an antivirus which is recommended ?

Comment: [No antivirus for linux?](http://superuser.com/q/55478)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, you don't.  There are very few virus-like things that hurt Linux systems, and most of the vectors for malicious code come through things like network services with known bugs.

The main reason to install traditional anti-virus software is to avoid carrying Windows viruses, inactive, in Windows document formats.

The standard choice is clamav, and perhaps a GUI front-end to that.  It should be packaged and available in your distribution.

In summary: anti-virus is the wrong sort of defence; keep your system patched instead.

Comment: _keep your system patched instead._ means ?

Comment: Apply the patches that your vendor supplies through the system update tools.  If you install software from anyone other than Fedora, follow their patching process.